# When needing to switch from single-node to cluster version of Apache IoTDB, how to switch from simple consensus to ratis consensus?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I previously installed 1.2 single-node version of Apache IoTDB, and use simpleConsensus protocol to synchronize data. I want to know what should I do when I want to expand IoTDB to cluster version, for example to three servers and and three copies? I checked the official guide and it says that for three copies settings, Ratis protocol needs to be used to ensure consistency, but this protocol is also a parameter for the first startup. Anyone know how can I change this protocol, or can I only setup a new cluser?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is suggested that you set up a new cluster for Apache IoTDB and then import the data using tsfile format in IoTDB. That will be the easier way instead of trying to reset the initializing parameter.